# How to use gradle to strip unused portions of Google Play Services

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to make my apk smaller and I also want to lower my method count because I'm getting afully close to the 65k method limit.

In this blog post https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71 it is talked about how to do it, but at the bottom theres a gist for a gradle script that will do this for you.

https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/d7c91b94214acd936e42

Still being new to Android Studio and gradle I was wondering if anyone had any luck with that gist. I haven't figured out where to put it in my build.gradle and was hoping someone could answer this question on SO. All I use Google Play Services for is GCM, so I think this can cut out a BUNCH of method calls.

Comment: Quoting [the third comment on the gist][1]: "just paste it to the bottom of your app's build.gradle file". Though you may want to try the plugin edition linked to later in the comments: https://gist.github.com/Takhion/10a37046b9e6d259bb31

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't sure if it had to go inside the android { } or outside. Also, I was confused because the file in the gist is a .gradle file. I will try that now.